# Can we encrypt using private key from .cer format in PHP ?

Tags: php, cryptography, openssl, public-key-encryption

From PHP function

```
openssl_public_encrypt ( string $data , string &$crypted , mixed $key )
```

does it work only with .pem for the $key? or we can use .cer or .crt?

Comment: I've got the answer, .cer is also work.

Comment: You should answer the question by clicking "Post Your Answer", not leaving a comment. Even if you asked the question. You should also talk about what's inside your `.cer`, `.pem` and `.crt` files. The extension does not tell you that. You could put a key in a file named `.exe`, that doesn't make it an executable.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your title is wrong because openssl_public_encrypt encrypts data with a public key, not with a private key. However, here is a list with common filename extensions for X.509 certificates are:

```
.pem               (Privacy Enhanced Mail) Base64 encoded DER certificate
                   enclosed between "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" and
                   "-----END CERTIFICATE-----"

.cer, .crt, .der   usually in binary DER form, but Base64-encoded certificates are
                   common too (see .pem above)

.p7b, .p7c         PKCS#7 SignedData structure without data, just certificate(s)
                   or CRL(s)

.p12               PKCS#12, may contain certificate(s) (public) and private keys
                   (password protected)

.pfx               PFX, predecessor of PKCS#12 (usually contains data in PKCS#12
                   format, e.g., with PFX files generated in IIS)
```